# How to highlight menu item in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a drawer menu like this. It has more than one item but we can assume all the same. Each one is an activity. I can change the activity from there. But I want to highlight background of the current activity. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Example screenshot:
[Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mMLP.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miHome"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />

</menu>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select an Item of the Navigation drawer then you can try out using this:

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

The getItem(int index) method gets the MenuItem then you can call the `setChecked(true);` on the menu item.

You can also highlight the item using this:

```
onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
```

[Here is the reference](http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/navigation-drawer-how-set-selected-item.html)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm new to this and I'm trying to do an assignment. I watched "https://youtu.be/do4vb0MdLFY". He uses <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout> and in it, I have a ConstaintLayout and <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
I added the NavigationView to the question.

I tried to implement onNavigationItemSelectedListener but that doesn't get called.
I switch activity via intent in "when expression" at 13:32 in the video. I want to show the user that he is in that exact activity.

Comment: Share your code here

Answer (score 0):

This is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGoToAdult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/main_btn_goto_adult"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnGoToChild"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="448dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGoToChild"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/main_btn_goto_child"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnGoToAdult"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="448dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.myapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.text.Html
import androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat
import androidx.core.view.get
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // navDrawer
    lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // navDrawer
        toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open_nav, R.string.close_nav)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        // navDrawer renk değiştirme
        val main = navView.menu[0]
        main.title = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
            "<background-color='#ff3824'>Anasayfa</ackground-color>",
            HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
        )

        // navDrawer
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.miHome -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Zaten anasayfadasın", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                R.id.miProductAdult -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this, ProductActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.miProductChild -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this, ProductChildActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.miContent -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this, ContentActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.miBuy -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this, BuyActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.miAbout -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this, AboutActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
            true
        }

        btnGoToChild.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ProductChildActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        btnGoToAdult.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ProductActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    // navDrawer
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // home icon
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.miHomeLogo -> Toast.makeText(this, "Zaten anasayfadasın", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        // navDrawer
        if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    // home icon
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.app_bar_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

}
```

This is app_bar_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miHomeLogo"
        android:title="@string/menu_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

nav_drawer_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miHome"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miProduct"
        android:title="@string/menu_products">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/miProductAdult"
                android:title="@string/menu_product_adult">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/miProductChild"
                android:title="@string/menu_product_child">
            </item>
        </menu>
    </item>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/miContent"
        android:title="@string/menu_content"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miBuy"
        android:title="@string/menu_buy"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miAbout"
        android:title="@string/menu_about"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: You have too much unnecessary code and you have not specified what have you tried nor have specified when you want thia to happen

Comment: I want to have screens (activities). I have MainActivity, ProductActivity, ProductChildActivity, ContentActivity, BuyActivity and AboutActivity.

Consider these like the Home, Explore, Subscriptions... in the Imgur screenshot I shared above. You can see that Explore has highligted background. I want that too. When I choose let's say BuyActivity in hamburger menu, I want to see Buy has background color.